# How can VueJS + Canvas-Context be linked together?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, vue.js, this

I use **VueJS** and I want to incorporate the `HTML-Canvas` with the `Canvas-Context`. I'd like to call the `context` from within my `components` like:

```
mounted() {
  this.$c.moveTo(100, 100)
  this.$c.lineTo(200, 200)
}
```

I started in my `main.js` with:

```
Vue.prototype.$c = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d')
```

Furthermore, I also don't know how to work with the keyword `this` in a construct like:

```
const Something = (x, y) => {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.draw() {
    this.$c.moveTo(100, 100)
    this.$c.lineTo(200, 200)
  }
}
```

So how can I combine the `canvas-context` and `VueJS`?

Answer (score 0):

One can set the prototype property, just as you are doing, before creating the Vue instances (as is described in [Adding Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html)).

As is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42971173/1575353), arrow functions don't bind to `this`, so make sure you use non-arrow functions.

> Don’t use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on an instance property or callback (e.g. `vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod())`). As arrow functions are bound to the parent context, `this` will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect and `this.myMethod` will be `undefined`.
> <sup>[1](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods)</sup>

See an example of this in the snippet below. Click the <kbd>draw</kbd> button to draw a line on the canvas.

```js
//wait for DOM to load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //set property on all Vue instances
  Vue.prototype.$c = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
  //create Vue instance
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    methods: {
      draw: function() {
        this.$c.beginPath();
        this.$c.moveTo(100, 100);
        this.$c.lineTo(200, 200);
        this.$c.stroke();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<div id="example">
  <button @click="draw">draw</button>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods</sub>