# vuejs data function returning object does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arrow-functions

I know vue expects data to be an function returning an object, so:

```
data () {
  return {}
}
```

works, but this doesn't work:

```
data: () => {

}
```

Why doesn't it work though? aren't' they both the same functions returning an object

Comment: Yes, it won't work. Read up about fat arrows and how to use them.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971081/use-arrow-function-in-vue-computed-does-not-work and there are more... please do some research before asking question in future...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because when you use `{` in [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you begin a block, not an object.

The following would work:

```
data: () => ({

})
```

Notice the `(` and `)`. From [MDN/Arrow Functions/Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax):

> ## Syntax - Advanced Syntax
>
> ```
> // Parenthesize the body of function to return an object literal expression:
> params => ({foo: bar})
> ```

But, anyway, don't use these in Vue. From the [API Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> Note that **you should not use an arrow function with the `data` property** (e.g. `data: () => { return { a: this.myProp }}`). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so `this` will not be the Vue instance as you expect and `this.myProp` will be undefined.

Update:
> **Per comment:** But even with the recommended way you still can't use `this` so what is the point?

You can. Consider `props`. You may want to mutate a prop's value (using `v-model`), which is not recommended. To achieve that functionality, the best practice is to create a internal property (e.g. `internalStuff`) in your `data` and initialize with the props value:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: ['stuff'],
  data() {
    return {internalStuff: this.stuff}; // this works fine, wouldn't with arrow functions
  },
  template: `<input type="text" v-model="internalStuff">`
}
```

Comment: but even with the recommende way you still can't use `this` so what is the point>