# Re-render view instantly in vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a chess program that searches at various depths, and I want to update the view between every depth searched, like after depth 1, after depth 2 and so one. So I pass a callback function to the chess solving function:

```
updateAiInfo: (depth) => {
  this.depth = depth;
  this.$forceUpdate();
  console.log('check');
}
```

It's being called between every depth searched, it prints check, and I know that the vue property depth is being changed, I have double checked that, but the vue does not update until after the chess solving function is finished. How can I update the vue view instantly?

Edit: Since it's an es6 arrow function, `this` will not change, it will stay bound to the vue instance. This function is passed to the chess function inside `mounted()`.

Comment: I think the problem is that my chess function is prioritised higher than view rendering.

Comment: Problem is with your arrow function syntax.

Comment: I don't get any error saying this.$forceUpdate() is not a function, and it should work this way so I really don't think that's the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971081/use-arrow-function-in-vue-computed-does-not-work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971081/use-arrow-function-in-vue-computed-does-not-work same is the case for functions inside method

Comment: You need to know more about `this` and also not to downvote way to fast :p

Comment: I know how this works in arrow functions, and I tried without arrow functions too anyways, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, deleting my answer, let me know when you get 
the solution.

Comment: There are microtasks, internal debouncing, and also scheduling, so forceUpdate will not be immediate.  How much delay are you getting before the output renders?

Comment: It's not rendering until my chess function is completetely finished, it's blocking the render. My ugly fix is that I resume execution in 10 ms with setTimeout(), but obviously it's not optimal.

Comment: @Mattias You may have to use [webworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to run your chess function, check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626821/5665870](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626821/5665870)