# Defining methods/functions on Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, function, object, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Is this:

```
saveUpdate() {
   // Some code
}
```

The same as:

```
saveUpdate: function() {
   // Some code
}
```

Is there a best practice (ES6) way to define methods on objects (specifically, Vue.js components)?

More context:
I am having trouble in my Vue.js application with the methods triggering properly in productions.  The methods I have defined seem to work fine in development - but once compiled for production they do not seem to behave in the same way.  I have read in the Vue.js documentation that all methods need to be defined as NEW separate functions, and I am now wondering if the way I am defining the methods; is actually not correct.

broader example:

```
...,
methods: {
  saveUpdate() {
   // Some code
  }
},
...
```

should I be doing something like:

```
...,
methods: {
  saveUpdate: () => {
   // Some code
  }
},
...
```

What is the modern, best practice or accepted way to do this?  Or am I looking in the wrong place and my declarations are just fine the way they are?

Comment: _"should I be doing something like <arrow function>"_  no. See [Use arrow function in vue computed does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971081/use-arrow-function-in-vue-computed-does-not-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this:

```
saveUpdate() {
   // Some code
}
```

Is syntactic sugar for:

```
saveUpdate: function() {
   // Some code
}
```

There's nothing different between the two bar the syntax. If you want an arrow function, I believe you need to use the second form:

```
saveUpdate: () => {
   // Some code in a lexical `this` scope (not useful in Vue computed).
}
```

Also note that the `->` syntax is invalid - it's a *fat* arrow `=>`. Although as [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) pointed out in the comments, you most likely won't want to use arrow functions in a Vue project as you'd lose the binding to `this` which is how you interact with your component.

Comment: It's highly unlikely to want an arrow function for any Vue instance function (computed / method / etc) since you would lose the all-important `this` reference to the instance itself

Comment: I see @Phil (not familiar with Vue) - I'll add that.

Comment: Are they also the same as:   saveUpdate: new function() { ... }?

Comment: No, `new` is used with a constructor.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No, it is a shorthand function - but with the same functionality, hence it's purely visual.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Jack's right on this one, it's just shorthand ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Just spent so much time looking for that @Phil :)

Comment: but without `,` between its invalid, so be a destructuring shorthand convention

Comment: @LawrenceCherone comma between what, exactly?

Comment: Without a comma it's invalid, because object properties are *always* separated by commas, as are array elements - it's **always** there.

Answer (score 2):

`saveUpdate() {...}` is ES6 shortcut for `saveUpdate: function() {...}`, so yes they are the same. Since Vue applications are commonly transpiled, there is no reason to not use the first option.

If a function is reused within application, it can be declared separately:

```
export function saveUpdate() {...}

...

export default {
  methods: { saveUpdate }
}
```

Arrows shouldn't be used for functions that expect to access Vue instance as `this`.

As [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) explains:

> All lifecycle hooks are called with their this context pointing to the
> Vue instance invoking it.
>
> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as
> `created: () => console.log(this.a)` or `vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod())`. Since an arrow function doesn’t have a this, this
> will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through
> parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined` or `Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function`.