# Problem when triggering a Vue function to change some component field

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Ok, so, be warned that this is a very newbie question since I'm only getting started with Vue.js.

So, I have a label and a button.
If the label is not visible, the button should say "Show Label" and when clicked... show the label.
When the label *is* visible, the button should say "Hide Label" and when clicked, hide it.

This (with computed properties) shows/hides the label, but does not change the button caption:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
            {{ message }}
            This is another thing: <b>{{thing}}</b><br>
            <span :title="title" @click="doSomething">NO TITLE</span>
            <ul v-for="item in items">
                <li>{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
            <button @click="labelVisible=!labelVisible">{{toggleMessage}}</button>
            <label v-if="labelVisible">This is my label</label>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({ 
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
                thing: 'thing',
                title: "This is the title",
                doSomething: ()=>{
                    alert("did something")
                },
                items: ["one", "two", "three"],
                labelVisible: true
            },
            computed: {
                toggleMessage: ()=>{
                    if (this.labelVisible) {
                        return "Hide Label";
                    }
                    else {
                        return "Show Label";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

This one (just with an on:click binding) doesn't do anything:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
            {{ message }}
            This is another thing: <b>{{thing}}</b><br>
            <span :title="title" @click="doSomething">NO TITLE</span>
            <ul v-for="item in items">
                <li>{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
            <button @click="buttonClicked">{{toggleMessage}}</button>
            <label v-if="labelVisible">This is my label</label>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({ 
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
                thing: 'thing',
                title: "This is the title",
                doSomething: ()=>{
                    alert("did something")
                },
                items: ["one", "two", "three"],
                labelVisible: true,
                toggleMessage: "Hide Label",
                buttonClicked: ()=> {
                    this.labelVisible = !this.labelVisible;
                    if (this.labelVisible) {
                        this.toggleMessage = "Hide Label";
                    }
                    else {
                        this.toggleMessage = "Show Label";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Preferably, I would like to get both of them working. But I still cannot see what I'm doing wrong. The Vue DevTools report no issue whatsoever...

---

**UPDATE:**

In the second case, when printing out the values of `labelVisible` and `toggleMessage`, they do change fine. It's just that the change is not reflected in the component.

Comment: It's because of an arrow functions, you can't do it because `this` there is not Vue's. More about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42971173/3125477

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut OK, so, I made the change in the first example (with computed properties) and it seems like what you suggest is true: eliminating the fat-arrow function declaration did work. The second example however, still doesn't work. (Perhaps, Vue doesn't know it has to re-render the component after the "manual" data change?)

Comment: But second example also contains arrow function: `buttonClicked: ()=>`

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut Yep, it does. The thing is I fixed that part, but it's still not working.

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut Jesus, just spotted it. Such a newbie miss...

Comment: It happens :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

OK, So, I'm posting myself the answer.

What @AlexBrohshtut spotted was right. Fat-arrow functions were an issue.

However, the most important part is that I hadn't put my function in `methods` (I had them in `data` section too). Pff...

So, **this** works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
            {{ message }}
            This is another thing: <b>{{thing}}</b><br>
            <span :title="title" @click="doSomething">NO TITLE</span>
            <ul v-for="item in items">
                <li>{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
            <button @click="buttonClicked">{{toggleMessage}}</button>
            <label v-if="labelVisible">This is my label</label>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({ 
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
                thing: 'thing',
                title: "This is the title",
                doSomething: ()=>{
                    alert("did something")
                },
                items: ["one", "two", "three"],
                labelVisible: true,
                toggleMessage: "Hide Label",

            },
            methods: {
                buttonClicked: function() {
                    console.log("button");
                    this.labelVisible = !this.labelVisible;
                    console.log(this.labelVisible);
                    if (this.labelVisible) {
                        this.toggleMessage = "Hide Label";
                    }
                    else {
                        this.toggleMessage = "Show Label";
                    }
                    console.log(this.toggleMessage);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```