# [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "update-user": "TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 vue components one is a list users and the other is the details of a user.

What I'm trying to do is, if I have to update a user's details then I want it to automatically update.
The problem I'm getting is that I'm getting this error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "update-user": "TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"
```

Here is my code for the user details component

```
<template>
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header">
       <span class="text-success" @click="updateUser">Save Changes</span>
     </div>
       <div class="card-body p-0">
           <div class="card card-primary card-outline card-outline-tabs">
               <div class="card-body">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" v-model="name">
                </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       props: ['emit', 'user'],
       data() {
           return {
               name: null,
           }
       },
       mounted() {

       },
       methods: {
           updateUser() {
               axios.put('/admin/users/'+this.user.id, this.name).then(response => {
                   this.emit.$emit('update-user', {
                       user: this.name
                   });
               });
           }
       }
   }
</script>
```

and my vue component with the list of users

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body>
            <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="user in showUsers">
                        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" @click="detail(user)">Manage</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['emit', 'users'],
        data() {
            return {
                perPage: 10,
                currentPage: 1,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            filterUsers() {
                return (this.userFilter === '') ? this.users : this.users.filter(u => { return u.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.userFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1; });
            },
            showUsers() {
                let start = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage;
                let end = start + this.perPage;
                return this.filterUsers.slice(start, end);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            detail(user) {
                this.emit.$emit('manage-user', { user: user });
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.emit.$on('update-user', payload => {
                this.user.name = payload.user.name;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In `this.user.name = payload.user.name` what is `this.user` referring to? There isn't a prop or data property called `user`

Comment: You're using arrow functions, which don't bind `this`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971081/use-arrow-function-in-vue-computed-does-not-work)

Comment: As Daniel said, the issue should be caused by set `name` for `this.user=undefined`. so try `this.users[0].name = payload.user.name;` or comment this line, it should eliminate the error.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I thought that `this.user` would be able to point to the `user.name` in this `<tr v-for="user in showUsers">`

Comment: @Sphinx - I didn't get the error but the user name didn't change when I clicked save

Comment: What is the `emit` prop?

Comment: And where is it emitting to?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights - it's this `emit: new Vue(),`

Comment: I've never heard it used that way. It works all fine aside from this error?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights it sounds OP pass one event bus (`new Vue()`) instance to other components

Answer (score 1):

The error you met is caused by `this.user` doesn't exists in the context inside `mounted() { this.emit.$on('update-user', ....}`.

As my understanding, you'd like to update the name of a specific user, but in that context, you only have all users (`this.users`) inside `mounted()`, you have to filter out that specific user then apply the update.

Below is one solution:

If `user.id` is unique, you can emit `user.id` and `user.name` from `updateUser`, then in `mounted`, find the specific user by `user.id`, then update it.

```
updateUser() {
   axios.put('/admin/users/'+this.user.id, this.name).then(response => {
       this.emit.$emit('update-user', {
           name: this.name,  // new user.name
           id: this.user.id // assuming user.id is unique
       });
   });
}
this.emit.$on('update-user', payload => {
    this.users.find(user => user.id===payload.id).name = payload.name; // find the user then update its name
});
```