# Vue method loses 'this' if triggered from emit?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue 3 latest.

Outer template:

```
<base-table @row-click="routeToEdit" ...>
  ... slots
</base-table>
```

Inner `BaseTable` component on my `tr` div:

```
<div @click="triggerRowClick(item)">...</div>
```

In methods of `BaseTable`:

```
  methods: {
    triggerRowClick(item) {
      this.$emit('row-click', { item });
    },
  },
```

And back out in my outer template... `this` is undefined and I have no access to `$router` or anything else :(

```
  methods: {
    routeToEdit: ({ item }) => {
      // this.$router.push('room_edit', { params: { room_id: item.id } });
      console.log(item);
    },
  },
```

Comment: Actually that does help, but indirectly. I used an arrow function when I should have used a regular function. One lamenting point, I HATE the current state of stack overflow where the last 5 questions I've asked all get voted to close. Usually questions are nuanced, which is why we have tags to begin with. For example, a beginner reading that thread in no way would likely pick up on that in the linked thread (the thread mentions to use arrow functions, and in this case that's what broke it because I should have used a regular function definition).

Comment: This is more a duplicate of [Use arrow function in vue computed does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971081/use-arrow-function-in-vue-computed-does-not-work). Even though that question talks about `computed`, the cause and solution are the same for your question.