# Typescript displays error for "this" Object saying TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' inside of vue methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

As I am still fairly new to writing questions, I apologise for possible misvoicing.

The problem:
I have a vue app with typescript.

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        setProgram: (program: Program)=>{
            this.program = program // TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
            this.step++ // TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

While I really like this feature of typescript, I really am sure, that "this" will not be undefined in this case.

How can I calm typescript down regarding the use of "this"?

Thank you very much everyone,
have a great day ahead!

Best Dom.

Comment: [TypeScript Support - Basic Usage](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage)

Comment: Yep, already set the recommended configuration. Still doesn't work ...

Comment: I specifically meant the `Vue.extend({ ... })` bit, ie `export default Vue.extend({ methods: { ... } })`

Comment: Okay, just tried that. Unfortunately still the same ...

Comment: I mean even if I did
`if(this!=undefined) this.program = program`
it will give me this error ...

Comment: Just had a look at your GitHub link. Why don't you simply continue to use `defineComponent` like you have in your other components?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use arrow function in vue computed does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42971173/283366)

Comment: Jep, that was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it!

"this" might be undefined if used inside lambda function :)

just change

`setProgram: (program: Program) => {`

to:

`setProgram: function (program: Program) {`

and it works ...